# how to get html div element innertext by id using regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm getting full html code using WebClient. But i need to get specified div from full html using regular expression.

for example:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
     <div id="left" style="float:left">this is a <b>left</b> side:<div style='color:red'> 1 </div>
     </div>
     <div id="right" style="float:left"> main side</div>
<div>
</body>
```

if i need div named 'main', function return

```
<div id="left" style="float:left">this is a <b>left</b> side:<div style='color:red'> 1 </div>
     </div>
     <div id="right" style="float:left"> main side</div>
```

If i need div named 'left', function return

```
this is a <b>left</b> side:<div style='color:red'> 1 </div>
```

If i need div named 'right', function return

```
 main side
```

How can i do?

Comment: Re your comment; HTML Agility Pack is correct; your html is wrong (malformed). Look at the thin just before `</body>`; that should be `</div>` - otherwise it is assumed to be a nested, unterminated *start* `<div>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do people insist on trying to use regex to parse html? You can probably do it if you exclude a whole host of edge-cases... but just use [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and you're done:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(...); // or Load
string main = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='main']").InnerHtml;
```

(note I'm assuming it is not xhtml; if it is xhtml, use `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`, and very similar code to the above)

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. But HtmlAgilityPack wrong work. When I'm downloading and testing on the previous example, doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='main']").InnerHtml is return 
     <div id="left" style="float:left">this is a <b>left</b> side:<div style="color:red"> 1 </div>
     </div>
     <div id="right" style="float:left"> main side</div>
<div>
</div>

Comment: Explained in comment to the question. In short, HTML Agility Pack is correct; the source html is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
string divname = "somename";
Match m = RegEx.Match(htmlContent, "<div[^>]*id="+divname+".*?>(.*?)</div");
string contenct = m.Groups[1].Tostring();
```

won't work if you have nested divs inside the desired div